# How store a tuple for NSGradient(colorsAndLocations:) in swift

Tags: swift, gradient, nsview, cgfloat, nscolor

To apply a gradient to a NSView, it seems best to make a class that inherits from NSView and override the draw method that sets a path and draws the gradient.

```
class GradientView: NSView {

var startColor = NSColor.red
var startPosition: CGFloat = 0
var endColor = NSColor.white
var endPosition: CGFloat = 1
var rotation: CGFloat = 0


override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.draw(dirtyRect)

    let bgGradient = NSGradient(colorsAndLocations: (startColor, startPosition), (endColor, endPosition))
    let path = NSBezierPath.init(rect: self.bounds)
    bgGradient?.draw(in: path, angle: rotation)
}
}
```

(Let me know if there's a better/easier way...)

It works great, but now I want to send a custom collection of colors & color-stops.  Note: *With this above method, I am limited to defining two (the startColor & startPosition and endColor & endPosition) only.

I'd like to use (an array ? of) tuples (containing several colors and their stop values).  The API to set a color and location is `NSGradient(colorsAndLocations:)` and uses the tuple `(NSColor, CGFloat)`.

I can add a parameter like `var colorStopArray: [(color: NSColor, stop: CGFloat)] = []` that creates an array of (such) tuples.  Also I can append values with: colorStopArray.append((startColor, startPosition)).

But how can I assign this to the API?

I've tried many methods and they all cause errors (eg. tried `NSGradient(colorsAndLocations: colorStopArray.flatMap{return ($0.color, $0.stop)})` )

So how can send many custom colors+locations to the above class (or hopefully a better suggestion) to create a custom gradient (which will then be drawn on my NSView)?

Comment: @matt Can you actually help?  Suggestion of code is good...

Comment: Unclear what the problem even is. Can you explain?

Comment: Side note: custom views that directly subclass `NSView` don't need to call super on `draw(_:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using matt's clues, I replaced the let line (using the more appropriate API `init(colors:atLocations:colorSpace:)`) :

```
let bgGradient = NSGradient(colorsAndLocations: (startColor, startPosition), (endColor, endPosition))
```

with

```
let bgGradient = NSGradient(colors: colorStopArray.map { $0.color }, atLocations: colorStopArray.map { $0.stop }, colorSpace: NSColorSpace.genericRGB)
```

Now it functions as I desired.

Comment: @matt Did you mention to map the inner components?  Please don't get upset I gave an answer that includes your name.  Now if someone with the same query, can get a range of solutions from different perspectives.  I believe one point of StackOverflow is to promote coding methods with an exchange of views.

Answer (score 0):

> With this above method, I am limited to defining two (the startColor & startPosition and endColor & endPosition) only.

No, you're not. This is a variadic; you can add as many tuples as you wish. This works fine:

```
let startColor = NSColor.red
let startPosition: CGFloat = 0
let middleColor = NSColor.blue
let middlePosition: CGFloat = 0.5
var endColor = NSColor.white
var endPosition: CGFloat = 1
let bgGradient = NSGradient(colorsAndLocations: 
    (startColor, startPosition), 
    (middleColor, middlePosition), 
    (endColor, endPosition))
```

If the question is "can I turn an array into a variadic?", then the answer is, unfortunately no. This feature ("splatting") is missing from the Swift language. The only way to call a variadic in Swift is as a variadic.

The initializer that lets you supply an array of colors and stop locations is [`init(colors:atLocations:colorSpace:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsgradient/1524459-init). So if that's what you want to supply, call that initializer instead.